If space is Polish, tight sequence has weakly convergent subsequence?
My book (Feynman-Kac-Type Theorems and Gibbs Measures on Path Space) says

We will be mainly interested in the case $S=C([0,\infty]) $ and $S=C(\mathbb{R})$. Since both are Polish spaces, a family of probability measures $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ has a weakly convergent sequence if it is tight.

(Here, $\mathscr{B}(S)$ is Borel $\sigma$-field.)
I'd like to know how Polish (i.e. separable and complete) space connects weakly convergence with tightness.
I know the definition of (1)"weakly convergent" and (2)"tight"
$$$$
Definition
Let $S$ be a metric space and $P$ a probability measure on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$.
(1) A sequence of probability measures $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ is weakly convergent to $P$ whenever
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}_{P_n}[f]=\mathbb{E}_P[f]$$
for every bounded and continuous real-valued function $f$ on $S$.
(Here $\mathbb{E}_P$ means expectation value about $P$.)
(2) A family $\mathscr{P} $ of probability measures on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ is tight whenever for every  $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact set $K_\epsilon \subset S$ such that $P'(K_\epsilon) >1-\epsilon$, for every $P'\in\mathscr{P}$ .
$$$$
Naively I think it's possible to make a weakly convergent subsequence by picking a probability measure $P$ form $\mathscr{P}$ and lining up $P$ to make subsequence $(P,P,...)$.  $\mathbb{E}_P[f]$ can be approximated, by restricting Borel measurable space to $(K_\epsilon,\mathscr{B}(K_\epsilon))$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, so $\mathbb{E}_P[f]$ is  finite and defined. Then $(P,P,...)$ is weakly convergent subsequence of $\mathscr{P}$.
How can I use Polishness to the proof?
Could you give me some ideas? I appreciate also good reference.

Prokhorov's Theorem.

The book you are reading is using one of the consequences of Prokhorov's theorem, i.e. in Polish spaces tightness and relative compactness in the weak topology are equivalent. The proof is non-trivial and you can find it in, for example, Chapter 1 Section 5 of Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures.

Thank you geetha290krm and Shiva so much, I'll check the proof!
